# Problem with XMLHttpRequest.DONE values supported in FF / Chrome

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a snippet of Javascript that I need to debug:

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            success = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Stepping through on Chrome and Firefox, I have found that the first "if" is failing.  I can see that `this.readyState` is set to `1`, which judging by the W3C spec should mean `OPENED`.  However `XMLHttpRequest.DONE` shows as `undefined` rather than `4` in Firebug.

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#states

Is there a problem in Firefox and Chrome whereby these values are not supported?

Comment: sometimes it works, sometime it don't, in the same firefox, sometimes httpRequest.DONE works but not XMLHttpRequest.DONE, weird

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be checking readyState against one of the numeric values, 4 in your case.

Comment: Great, that's sorted it.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: A small note: `XMLHttpRequest.DONE` *should* hold the numeric value `4`, but it is not implemented in IE8 and below.

Answer (score 7):

Some browser does not know `XMLHttpRequest.DONE` property, so you should check it as follows before first 'if':

```
var DONE =  (typeof XMLHttpRequest.DONE !== 'undefined') ? XMLHttpRequest.DONE : 4;
```

Comment: Please explain (in your answer) how this answers the OP's question.  As it, this is just a snippet of code without much context.

Comment: As this returns `undefined` isn't it shorter to just `XMLHttpRequest.DONE || 4` instead?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest.DONE` is equal `4` why use 'if' just use `4`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DONE value that the httpRequest variable already has:

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            success = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think the `this` value in your `this.done` refers to the `httpRequest` variable?

Comment: @AJarofClay as a matter of fact it _is_ the XMLHttpRequest that is also represented by the variable `httpRequest` :) If you execute this example with a `console.log(this)` you can test for it :)