# How to play sound when new message received (chat system)

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, notifications

I am trying to make a notification sound happen every time I receive a message. I know how to make it happen every time I send a message but not receive. Relevant code is here.

What should be changed in the javascript?

chat.php is the website that will be playing the sound.

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  include_once "php/config.php";
  if(!isset($_SESSION['unique_id'])){
    header("location: login.php");
  }
?>
<?php include_once "header.php"; ?>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="chat-area">
      <header>
        <?php 
          $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['user_id']);
          $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `unique_id` = {$user_id}");
          if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
          }else{
            header("location: users.php");
          }
        ?>
        <a href="users.php" class="back-icon"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
        <img src="php/images/<?php echo $row['img']; ?>" alt="">
        <div class="details">
          <span><?php echo $row['fname']. " " . $row['lname'] ?></span>
          <p><?php echo $row['status']; ?></p>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="chat-box">

      </div>
      <form action="#" class="typing-area">
        <input type="text" class="incoming_id" name="incoming_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="message" class="input-field" placeholder="Type a message here..." autocomplete="off">
        <button><i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i></button>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>

  <script src="javascript/chat.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Realtime Chat App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"/>
</head>
```

users.php

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  include_once "php/config.php";
  if(!isset($_SESSION['unique_id'])){
    header("location: login.php");
  }
?>
<?php include_once "header.php"; ?>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="users">
      <header>
        <div class="content">
          <?php 
            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `unique_id` = {$_SESSION['unique_id']}");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
              $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
            }
          ?>
          <img src="php/images/<?php echo $row['img']; ?>" alt="">
          <div class="details">
            <span><?php echo $row['fname']. " " . $row['lname'] ?></span>
            <p><?php echo $row['status']; ?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="php/logout.php?logout_id=<?php echo $row['unique_id']; ?>" class="logout">Logout</a>
      </header>
      <div class="search">
        <span class="text">Select an user to start chat</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name to search...">
        <button><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="users-list">
  
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <script src="javascript/users.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript/users.js

```
const searchBar = document.querySelector(".search input"),
searchIcon = document.querySelector(".search button"),
usersList = document.querySelector(".users-list");

searchIcon.onclick = ()=>{
  searchBar.classList.toggle("show");
  searchIcon.classList.toggle("active");
  searchBar.focus();
  if(searchBar.classList.contains("active")){
    searchBar.value = "";
    searchBar.classList.remove("active");
  }
}

searchBar.onkeyup = ()=>{
  let searchTerm = searchBar.value;
  if(searchTerm != ""){
    searchBar.classList.add("active");
  }else{
    searchBar.classList.remove("active");
  }
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "php/search.php", true);
  xhr.onload = ()=>{
    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
        if(xhr.status === 200){
          let data = xhr.response;
          usersList.innerHTML = data;
        }
    }
  }
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send("searchTerm=" + searchTerm);
}

setInterval(() =>{
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "php/users.php", true);
  xhr.onload = ()=>{
    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
        if(xhr.status === 200){
          let data = xhr.response;
          if(!searchBar.classList.contains("active")){
            usersList.innerHTML = data;
          }
        }
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}, 500);
```

javascript/chat.js

```
const form = document.querySelector(".typing-area"),
incoming_id = form.querySelector(".incoming_id").value,
inputField = form.querySelector(".input-field"),
sendBtn = form.querySelector("button"),
chatBox = document.querySelector(".chat-box");

form.onsubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
}

inputField.focus();
inputField.onkeyup = ()=>{
    if(inputField.value != ""){
        sendBtn.classList.add("active");
    }else{
        sendBtn.classList.remove("active");
    }
}

sendBtn.onclick = ()=>{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "php/insert-chat.php", true);
    xhr.onload = ()=>{
      if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
          if(xhr.status === 200){
              inputField.value = "";
              scrollToBottom();
              var audio = new Audio("php/sounds/good_notification.mp3");
              audio.play();
          }
      }
    }
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
chatBox.onmouseenter = ()=>{
    chatBox.classList.add("active");
}

chatBox.onmouseleave = ()=>{
    chatBox.classList.remove("active");
}

setInterval(() =>{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "php/get-chat.php", true);
    xhr.onload = ()=>{
      if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
          if(xhr.status === 200){
            let data = xhr.response;
            chatBox.innerHTML = data;
            if(!chatBox.classList.contains("active")){
                scrollToBottom();
              }
          }
      }
    }
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("incoming_id="+incoming_id);
}, 500);

function scrollToBottom(){
    chatBox.scrollTop = chatBox.scrollHeight;
  }
```

php/insert-chat.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['unique_id'])){
        include_once "config.php";
        $outgoing_id = $_SESSION['unique_id'];
        $incoming_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incoming_id']);
        $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);
        if(!empty($message)){
            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `messages` (incoming_msg_id, outgoing_msg_id, msg)
                                        VALUES ({$incoming_id}, {$outgoing_id}, '{$message}')") or die();
        }
    }else{
        header("location: login.php");
    }  
?>
```

php/get-chat.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['unique_id'])){
        include_once "config.php";
        $outgoing_id = $_SESSION['unique_id'];
        $incoming_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['incoming_id']);
        $output = "";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `messages` LEFT JOIN `users` ON users.unique_id = messages.outgoing_msg_id
                WHERE (outgoing_msg_id = {$outgoing_id} AND incoming_msg_id = {$incoming_id})
                OR (outgoing_msg_id = {$incoming_id} AND incoming_msg_id = {$outgoing_id}) ORDER BY `msg_id`";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                if($row['outgoing_msg_id'] === $outgoing_id){
                    $output .= '<div class="chat outgoing">
                                <div class="details">
                                    <p>'. $row['msg'] .'</p>
                                </div>
                                </div>';
                }else{
                    $output .= '<div class="chat incoming">
                                <img src="php/images/'.$row['img'].'" alt="">
                                <div class="details">
                                    <p>'. $row['msg'] .'</p>
                                </div>
                                </div>';
                }
            }
        }else{
            $output .= '<div class="text">No messages are available. Once you send message they will appear here.</div>';
        }
        echo $output;
    }else{
        header("location: login.php");
    }

?>
```

The website auto updates every .5 secs so it would show a message sooner.

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code you have shared.

Comment: Be aware that you have a big SQL injection vulnerability here. Someone submitting a message with a `'` character in it will break your code. Look into parameterized queries.

Comment: I will see what I can do. Sorry if I hurt your head a bit. I'm new so I don't get everything the best. I will try.

Comment: @ceejayoz I just checked and I put a ~~~ ` ~~~ and nothing happened. It just sent. Nothing went wrong

Comment: Not a back-tick (`), a regular apostrophe (').

Comment: Sorry I typed the wrong thing. Yeah, I tried both and it doesn't error

Comment: In users.js, try checking readyState against `4` rather than `.DONE`, per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6898590/1447509)

Comment: @cssyphus How would I do that? Can you provide what my code would look like after I were to add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I meant in your chat.js file...

It would look something like this:

```
xhr.onload = ()=>{
  if(xhr.readyState !== undefined && xhr.readyState === 4){
      if(xhr.status === 200){
          inputField.value = "";
          scrollToBottom();
          var audio = new Audio("php/sounds/good_notification.mp3");
          audio.play();
      }
  }
}
```

This is just brainstorming off the cuff, untested, which is why I submitted it as a comment.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I will test that out. Do you know how to make my website make a sound when I receive a message? The answer down there doesn't help.

Comment: You would do that in the same file, down further in the setInterval where you are checking for new messages... if there are new messages (I presume you can check for that), just add the same code re creating a new Audio() element and using the `play()` method on it.   *If you aren't sure how to check for new messages, just check the length of the current list of message containers (var) and then check (create another var) for the number of new messages in the incoming list and compare them.*

Comment: Could you give me an idea on what to do? I know how to make variables but not on how to define what the variable is. I know this... `var USER = "javascriptisthebest"`. How would I define what the length of the current list is if my list is reloading every half a second.

Comment: So the `data` variable that is received in `let data = xhr.response` is a string, and each separate chat message div contains `"chat ` (including the trailing space).  You can count the number of occurrences of that string (quote-c-h-a-t-space) and that will tell you how many messages you are getting in that feed.  You can cache that number away *(even storing it in a hidden input field `input type="hidden"`)* so that the next interval can read it and now you know how many you got last time. You also just calculated how many you received this time, and if different play the sound.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I needed this. I marked your answer as the accepted answer. [My website in developement.](https://sign-up-hello-world.000webhostapp.com/ChatApp/)

Comment: Please thumbs up this question. Thanks.